# vs2015 FTP publish changed files

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-2015, publish, webdeploy

Unfortunately I don't have the luxury to use Web Deploy on a server. How can I update only the changed files over FTP in Visual Studio 2015?

Sounds like a question which has already been answered, right? Well I found questions for previous versions without good answers but that it is possible for publishing individual files.I still did not found a solution to publishing changed files over FTP. Is is just still not there over these years?

There is this option to allow Pre compile during publishing. But this does not have any effect with the default settings.

I am now just publishing it locally, then publish it using FileZilla because that one offers an option to only "overwrite if newer". Would be better to have this automated in VS.

Is there perhaps a possibility to use Web Deploy's logic over FTP?